# SQL version of write for spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to just use SQL in a SQL notebook on databricks. I have a query on a table, I want to save the result of the query to S3. Again I'm only using SQL. I know how to do this with pyspark and scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## As Directory

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3a://bucket/folder'
USING parquet
SELECT * FROM test_table;
```

## As Table

Step 1:

```
CREATE targetTable (a string, b string) USING datasource LOCATION 's3a://bucket/folder' PARTITION BY (b)
```

Step 2:

As Overwrite:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE targetTable PARTITION (b = test) 
SELECT a, b FROM sourceTable
```

As append:

```
INSERT INTO targetTable
SELECT a, b FROM sourceTable
```

reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert.html

Comment: I don't think of doing it that way . I have used those functions interesting idea